# JavaFX WebView Dnd in JFXPane is Exception

Tags: swing, javafx

JavaFX WebView is integrated into Swing and JFXPane is used. It is found that when dragging, the virtual shadow cannot be displayed normally.

The abnormal situation is shown in the screenshot below
[image: image should appear when dragging]

How to display the false shadow normally?

Environmental information：

JDK-17
javafx-20
macos(13.4 (22F66))

tip:20230613 Supplementary error

```java
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:733)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateTransferable(DataTransferer.java:943)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer$2.run(DataTransferer.java:1883)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:789)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:733)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.translateTransferable(DataTransferer.java:943)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer$2.run(DataTransferer.java:1883)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:789)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

```java
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainTest extends JFrame {

    private Scene scene;

    public MainTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getRootPane().setBorder(null);
        JFXPanel jFXPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            final WebView webView = new WebView();
            final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            borderPane.setCenter(webView);
            engine.load("https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#simple-list");
            this.scene = new Scene(borderPane);
            jFXPanel.setScene(scene);
        });
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(jFXPanel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame jFrame = new MainTest();
            jFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
            jFrame.pack();
            jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you'll need a complete working example. Maybe you've found a bug.

Comment: You'll probably also need to include your os, javafx version and java version.

Comment: I get a similar issue, except my shows a circle with a line through it like there is an error of some sort. I also get an error when I drop. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.javafx.embed.EmbeddedSceneDSInterface.getMimeTypes()" because "this.this$0.fxDragSource" is null` You should add an image of when the dragging works, then you could probably file an issue with openjfx.

Comment: It actually seems to be a bit simpler. You can also try to drag a normal image from the jfxpane. I tried running your example in a JavaFX application and it works better, though not as well as firefox.

Comment: Due to the lack of code case reference, my own implementation is not clear.